# How to select a class in css that includes a symbol?

Tags: html, css

Hello and here is my example

```css
.*test{color:blue;}
```

```html
<p class="*test">Hi</p>
```

`

But it doesn't work that way
I neeed to select all classes with the *test and includes the symbol but it just doesn't work

Please Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape it

```css
.\*test {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="*test">Hi</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [attribute*=value] selector matches every element whose attribute value containing a specified value **including a symbol**.

Example :

```
*[class*="*symbol"] {
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
*[class*="*symbol"] {
  background: #ffff00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="first_symbol">The first div element.</div>
<div class="second">The second div element.</div>
<div class="*symbol">The symbol.</div>
<p class="*symbol">The symbol paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```